# Is there a benefit to using Typescript Async/Await over Promises?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

At this time, is there a benefit to using Typescript Async/Await over Promises?

I have a single page app written in typescript and I have not used async/await.

Is it time to convert over to using async/await instead of promises?

My concerns:

1. Is there a speed difference? TS is currently targerts ES5 in my project, and the resulting code appears rather wordy compared to a promise.
2. What about Promise.all()?  Is there a way to do this with typscript async/await

Comment: Because of browser support?

Answer (score 4):

I'd say the benefits of async/await ( btw there are javascript features not only Typescript) is that it allows to have clearer code if you have a snippet of code with multiple promises. Exception handling will also be more seamless.

However, it doesn't mean you have to convert to async/ await. Promises still will be the underlying element used by async / await, they aren't going anywhere.

- The better way to know would be to benchmark it yourself, but I don't think there would be a massive difference.
- async / await is pretty much just a wrapper other promise so anything that will return a Promise will work. It means that

  ```
  Promise.all(promises).then(data => console.log(data));
  ```

  can be converted to

  ```
  const data = await Promise.all(promises);
  console.log(data),
  ```

Answer (score 2):

> and the resulting code appears rather wordy compared to a promise.

The "wordy" result should not be your concern, and has no causality *per se* on bad performance.

If you want to check for a performance issue, benchmark it in production-like conditions.

You should however **care for your source code not being too wordy**, clear for yourself and your colleagues.

Consider this :

```
async function startGame() {
  var currentScore = 5;
  console.log('Game Started! Current score is ' + currentScore);
  currentScore = await levelOne(currentScore);
  console.log('You have reached Level One! New score is ' + currentScore);
  currentScore = await levelTwo(currentScore);
  console.log('You have reached Level Two! New score is ' + currentScore);
  currentScore = await levelThree(currentScore);
  console.log('You have reached Level Three! New score is ' + currentScore);
}
```

over this :

```
var startGame = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var currentScore = 5;
    console.log('Game Started! Current score is ' + currentScore);
    resolve(currentScore);
});
startGame.then(levelOne)
.then(function (result) {
    console.log('You have reached Level One! New score is ' + result);
    return result;
})
.then(levelTwo).then(function (result) {
    console.log('You have reached Level Two! New score is ' + result);
    return result;
})
.then(levelThree).then(function (result) {
    console.log('You have reached Level Three! New score is ' + result);
});
```

(example from https://dev.to/siwalik/async-programming-basics-every-js-developer-should-know-in-2018-a9c)

---

As already said, async / await are just wrappers over Promises.

Another interesting point in favor of using `async/await` is that error handling is much more natural with the "synchronous looking code" with async/await than it is with Promises !

---

And the Promise.all point has already been covered by Axnyff's answer.